# UIImagePickerController Crashing Monotouch

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, xamarin.ios

I am trying to write an application, but it is constantly crashing when using the uiimagepickercontroller.   I thought that it might be because I was not disposing of the picker after each use, but it will often freeze up on first run as well.  Usually I'll take a picture and it just freezes, never asking to "use" the picture.

Do you have any suggestions?   Here is my code.  Has anyone gotten this to work?

```
 public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        myPicker = new UIImagePickerController();
        myPicker.Delegate = new myPickerDelegate(this);

        myAlbumButton.Clicked += delegate {
                if(UIImagePickerController.IsSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary)){
                    myPicker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary;
                    myPicker.AllowsEditing = true;
                    this.PresentModalViewController (myPicker, true);
                }else{
                Console.WriteLine("cannot get album");  
            }
        };


        myCameraButton.Clicked += delegate {
            if(UIImagePickerController.IsSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)){
                myPicker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
                //myPicker.AllowsEditing = true;
                this.PresentModalViewController (myPicker, true);
            }else{
                Console.WriteLine("cannot get camera"); 
            }

        };

    }


    private class myPickerDelegate : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
    {
        private TestView _vc;

        public myPickerDelegate ( TestView controller):base()
        {
            _vc = controller;   
        }

        public override void FinishedPickingImage (UIImagePickerController myPicker, UIImage image, NSDictionary editingInfo)
        {
            // TODO: Implement - see: http://go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=T%3aMonoTouch.Foundation.ModelAttribute

            _vc.myImageView.Image = image;
            myPicker.DismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true);
        }
 }
```

Comment: The code looks reasonable to me....if you step through, where does it crash?

Comment: i'd also check out tweetstation - miguel (if i remember correctly) uses a singleton camera class - maybe copy his pattern?

Comment: I have the same issue.  Do you have a solution for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call your event handlers code from the main thread by using BeginInvokeOnMainThread().

Answer (score 0):

So my issue was very similar.

Instead of having a delegate class, I had the delegates inline for the picker.
For some reason the app froze every time after talking the image, not stopping in any breakpoint after that.

The solution that worked for me was to use this book:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/33770921/Professional-iPhone-Programming-with-MonoTouch-and-NET-C